# Discord.py using multiple permission check decorators on command methods

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py, python-decorators

I'm making a command `test`.
I only want the user to be able to use the command when they either;

- Are the bot owner
- Have the `manage_channels` permission

At the moment I am doing

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
@commands.check(commands.is_owner())
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.reply("Success!")
```

But as soon as I - the bot owner - try to use it without the `manage_channels` permission it does not work. I assume it is blocked by @commands.has_permissions() as soon as it sees I don't have the permission?

I know I could always just check in the method itself, but I understand using the decorators is the better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `commands.check_any` decorator

```py
@client.command()
@commands.check_any(commands.is_owner(), commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True))
async def ...
```

#### Reference:

- [`commands.check_any`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check_any)